# model angular 4,change the view from an updated model

Tags: angular

Hi i have this component an I call  'updateUserInfo' from a service but I'm unable to change the value in the view can anyone help me please?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-menu',
    templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css'],

});

export class MenuComponent  {

    firstname = "aaa";

    constructor() { }

    updateUserInfo(user){
        this.firstname = "ciao";

    }
}
```

Comment: what does your html look like?

Comment: <div class="profile-usertitle-name">
                {{firstname}}
            </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example yoг have user.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers, Request, RequestMethod} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {


    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

 getUserName() {
     let headers = new Headers();
     headers.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
     headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json;');
    return this.http.get("http://YourUrl",{ headers: headers})
                      .map((response: Response) =>response.json())
    }
}
```

This is your component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';

@Component({ 
 selector: 'app-menu', 
 templateUrl: './menu.component.html', 
 styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css'],
 providers: [UserService] 
}) 

export class MenuComponent {

firstname = "aaa";

constructor(private userService: UserService) {
 ////dont use in constructor many codes, best of use in ngOnInit
 }

ngOnInit() {
       this.userService.getUserName()
         .subscribe(response=> {this.updateUserInfo(response.user.name);});
}

updateUserInfo(user){
   this.firstname = user;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help you.Not at all.

Answer (score 0):

You must call your function updateUserInfo in constructor

Comment: The problem is that I have a service that call the updateUserInfo function

Comment: @GiovanniPolì you must use servise in component, and in subscribe call updateUserInfo()

Comment: I think I cannot do it alone, i would appreciate your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Component({ 
     selector: 'app-menu', 
     templateUrl: './menu.component.html', 
     styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css'],
   }) 

 export class MenuComponent {

 firstname = "aaa";

 constructor() {
  this.updateUserInfo("text");  ///here called function
 }

updateUserInfo(user){
    this.firstname = "ciao";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function inside the controller, that function should be called from inside the component, for example:

```
<div class="profile-usertitle-name"> {{ firstname }} </div>
<button (click)="updateUserInfo('Mario')">Change name</button>
```

If you are calling a service, the service should have a "promise" (could be a observable) that you subscribe to that. Like this:

```
constructor(private myService : MyService) {
    myService.load().subscribe((user) => updateUserInfo(user));
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I have a service that call the updateUserInfo function

Comment: But if you have to call from a service the method `.updateUserInfo()` which it is inside a component something is wrong. Usually you should inject the service in the component, not the other way around. Probably this is more a architecture error, you probably are not using the pieces as they should